# Alpine image inconsistency in Docker file and build.sbt file

Tags: docker, sbt, alpine-linux, adoptopenjdk

The project is built using "sbt".The image is built through a script(`docker build --pull=true -t <IMAGE-NAME> -f Dockerfile .`)The parent image which is mentioned in Dockerfile is this one:

```
FROM <Remote_docker_hub>/alpine:3.15
```

In build.sbt file, the base docker image is adoptopenjdk16:jdk16.0.1_9-alpine like:

```
dockerBaseImage := <Remote_docker_hub>/adoptopenjdk16:jdk16.0.1_9-alpine
```

When I am building the image, I was assuming that the container will have alpine-3.15 but it is pulling 3.14. Not sure if this is the reason but looks like dockerBaseImage is overriding the Dockerfile.

Even if dockerBaseImage is overriding the Alpine version, the base image is just JDK, then why its pulling its own OS? Is there a way I can make sure that the JDK will just create a java container and the OS will be the one mentioned in Dockerfile?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the Dockerfile you mention and the sbt setting interact?  Are you using sbt-native-packager to build the image, or something else?  An image usually includes a Linux distribution base of some sort along with whatever it packages, and there's no way to combine images; if that AdoptOpenJDK image is built on Alpine 3.15 then that's what you'll get.

Comment: thanks @David Maze for answering. I realized it later that I am using a separate docker script to build the image which takes the value from sbt.